# Find the relative matrix of a linear transformation between function space.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The question is

> The linear transformation $L: V \rightarrow V$ in vector space $V=\left\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\middle| f(t)=\alpha\cos(t)+\beta\sin(t),\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ is defined as $L(f)(t)=f''(t)-f'(t)$. When the ordered basis of $V$ is given as $B=\left\{\cos(t),\sin(t)\right\}$, find the relative matrix of the linear transformation $L$.

The answer is $\left[L\right]_B=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\
 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$
**My approach:**
$$f'(x)=-\alpha\sin(t)+\beta\cos(t)$$
$$f''(t)=-\alpha\cos(t)-\beta\sin(t)$$
$$\Rightarrow L(f)(t)=(-\alpha-\beta)\cos(t)+(\alpha-\beta)\sin(t)$$

I got stuck at this point. the sign of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of the coefficient of $\cos$ and $\sin$ seems to match with the sign of each row of the answer. So I tried to make sense of it but failed. I'm beginning to feel that I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way but currently unable to find another path. Any hints will be very helpful. thanks!

Comment: The columns in the matrix representation $[L]_{B}$ of the linear transformation $L$ relative the ordered basis $B=\{\cos(t), \sin(t)\}$ are the images of the basis vectors under $L$ expressed as column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ using the basis $B$.

Comment: I understand that $[L]_B$ is the image of the basis vectors. But what do mean of expressed as column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using the basis $B$?

Comment: For any (real) finite dimensional vector space $V$ you always have that $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for some $n$. In this case such an isomorphism can be given by letting $\cos(t)$ correspond to $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\sin(t)$ to $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. Then, for example, $L(\cos(t))=\sin(t)-\cos(t)$ would correspond to $\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ i.e. the first column in the matrix representation

Comment: Commonly, the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ would be called the [coordinate vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) of $\cos(t)$ relative the basis $\{\cos(t), \sin(t)\}$

Comment: Can you explain a bit of why $L(\cos(t))=\sin(t)-\cos(t)?

Comment: The linear transformation $L$ is defined as $L(f)(t) = f’’(t)-f’(t)$ and I used  $f(t) = \cos(t)$

Comment: Now I understand! So, the only thing I need to do is to image the basis of $V$ to $V$ as noted by the linear transformation $L$. Does that mean that the "My approach" in the question body has nothing to do with the actual solving of this problem?

Comment: Your approach is related because by linearity $L(a\cos(t) + b\sin(t)) = a L(\cos(t)) + bL(\sin(t))$ so you have calculated the image of $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$ under $L$, at least implicitly. It is a bit unfocused though and the most straight forward solution would instead be to only calculate $L(\cos(t))$ and $L(\sin(t))$ and then express these using coordinate vectors.